# CreateTransaction using Trongrid API

Tags: curl, blockchain, cryptocurrency, tron

I am trying to create a tron transaction using trongrid APi.
But when I do so, I get the following error:

*{
"Error": "class org.tron.core.exception.ContractValidateException : Validate TransferContract error, no OwnerAccount."
}*

There is the api: https://developers.tron.network/reference/createtransaction

There is the curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://api.shasta.trongrid.io/wallet/createtransaction \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --data '
{
  "to_address": "41e9d79cc47518930bc322d9bf7cddd260a0260a8d",
  "owner_address": "415c543dca23f94f3e3db585368cb070204efeca0f",
  "amount": 100000
}
'
```

Comment: Do you find answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `TRON-PRO-API-KEY` header.
Here is a an example:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/createtransaction \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'TRON-PRO-API-KEY: 25f66928-0b70-48cd-9ac6-da6f8247c663' \
  -d '{
    "to_address": "41e9d79cc47518930bc322d9bf7cddd260a0260a8d",
    "owner_address": "41D1E7A6BC354106CB410E65FF8B181C600FF14292",
    "amount": 1000
}'
```

You can create your api key [here](https://www.trongrid.io/price).

Notice that this will only create the transaction string, you still need to sign it and broadcast to the network:

**Create -> Sign -> Broadcast -> (wait) -> Lookup and get receipt**